# VBS to Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to convert the script from VBS to Powershell. I have looked into Microsoft documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221101.aspx), but couldn't find the answer.

The VBS script instantiates the COM object and the uses it like this:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("COM.ObjName")
Set stringValue = "blah"
obj(stringValue).Metod #need help here
```

I know how to create a COM object in PowerShell, but I don't know how to convert `obj(stringValue).Method` to Powershell.

UPD. I figured out that `obj` is actually a container of other objects (maybe dictionary?).

UPD 2. The question transforms to: How to call the `[]` operator of the COM object from powershell?
The object browser in Visual Studio displays the signature of this operator as:

```
public virtual type1 this[ref object index] {get; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues solved. The `Com.ObjName` under study appears to be a collection. Because, when I looked at its structure using the "OLE/COM Object Viewer," I found out that it had a parametrized `Item` property. So, Powershell loaded this object with this property, but didn't automatically create an index operator for it.
So what in VBScript looked like:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("COM.ObjName")
Set stringValue = "blah"
obj(stringValue).Metod #need help here
```

transforms into:

```
$obj = New-Object -ComObject "Com.ObjName"
$stringValue = "blah"
$obj.Item[$stringValue].Method()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create the object and pipe it to get-member , it may help you .
Example :

```
PS>$sch=new-object -ComObject ("Schedule.Service")                           
PS>$sch |get-member                                                          


   TypeName : System.__ComObject#{2faba4c7-4da9-4013-9697-20cc3fd40f85}      

Name            MemberType Definition                                        
----            ---------- ----------                                        
Connect         Method     void Connect (Variant, Variant, Variant, Variant) 
GetFolder       Method     ITaskFolder GetFolder (string)                    
GetRunningTasks Method     IRunningTaskCollection GetRunningTasks (int)      
NewTask         Method     ITaskDefinition NewTask (uint)                    
Connected       Property   bool Connected () {get}                           
ConnectedDomain Property   string ConnectedDomain () {get}                   
ConnectedUser   Property   string ConnectedUser () {get}                     
HighestVersion  Property   uint HighestVersion () {get}                      
TargetServer    Property   string TargetServer () {get}
```

Comment: Sorry, how can I determine what method is invoked when brackets operator `()` is called?

Comment: I really dont know, I guess it depends of the com object

Comment: @Kayasax: try with: `$comobj.method.overloaddefinitions`

Comment: You can also use "OLE/COM Object Viewer" to peek inside a class.